# Woocommerce - Add line to text to billing details

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to customise the headers in the checkout pages. We're selling flowers. I have used a few replace string commands to change "billing details" to say "are you buying for yourself?" and "Ship to a different address" to say "are you sending to someone else?"...

My question is, I now have the headings as per the attached image. I would now like to the two headings to look the same (so "are you buying for yourself" shouldn't be bold etc).

Also, I want to add a line of text underneath each heading.

If anyone could please tell me how to do this, I'd very much appreciate it.

I'm very new at this - so i think it has something to do with the CSS file now, but I have no idea!

Thanks in advance!

Michelle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXPWM.jpg)

Comment: yes you are correct you need to modify the style through css and the easiest way for you is to go to customize and find something called additional css from there you can modify the styling that you need and if you need more help about finding please post your website link so

Comment: I have one called custom.css which i guess it goes into. But I have no idea how to reference these items and change their appearance.  Here is the link - https://flowersforeveryone.feedmybeta.com/checkout/  Thanks!!

Comment: that's code is just to change the text try the below CSS code if you want this two heading to look like the pic

Comment: The code in the functions.php file is --                                                                    add_filter('gettext', 'custom_strings_translation', 20, 3);

function custom_strings_translation( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

  switch ( $translated_text ) {
    case 'Ship to a different address?' : 
      $translated_text =  __( 'Are you sending to someone else?', '__x__' )
   ; 
      break;
    case 'We will try our best to deliver your order on the specified date.' : 
      $translated_text =  __( '', '__x__' )
   ; 
      break;

  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want it to look like below:

[image]

add the following this line to your css file:

```
.woocommerce-billing-fields h3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid; 
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.woocommerce-checkout label span
{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Comment: perfect... thank you!!! How do I go about adding a line of text under each one? Thanks so much!

Comment: already added the lines for u, you want them to be like pic right or i understand wrong?

Comment: sorry.. i meant a string of  text! I Underneath "Are you buying for yourself" I want to say "Only complete the below section:" and under "are you buying for someone else" I want to say "Complete this section as well:" - but in smaller text.. if this makes sense!

Comment: that's required template modification because right now you are using the checkbox filed for shipping to different address  and you are changing only the text so if you need to do it in different way you need to customize the checkout template

Comment: okay thanks.. that sounds a little above my skill level! one more tiny question if I may please - If I want to move "Are you sending to someone else" a little further to the right of the checkbox, is there any easy way to do that? We want a little more space between the checkbox and the words! :)

Comment: just add this padding-left: 16px; to .woocommerce-checkout label span and if you found my answer useful i will be appropriated it you accept it :)